# Php file download returning incorrect output

Tags: php, mysql, database, oop, blob

I'm trying to download a file from my database and I'm getting back a php file as an output. But when I use var_dump, I'm able to get the output shown in Figure 1 [image: Figure1]

and Figure 2.

[image: Figure2]

I want to be able to download the file as its actual file type. (i.e. as a pdf) Can anyone please help me with this? Thanks in advance :)

Here is my download code:

```
 try {
//if id is set then get file from database
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    //pump id into function getDBFiles to pull file with matching id
    $Download->getDBFiles($id);
    //get array containing file details from function getDBFiles
    $getFiles = $Download->getMessages();
    //var_dump($getFiles);
    $size = $getFiles['size'];
    $type = $getFiles['type'];
    $name = $getFiles['name'];
    $content = $getFiles['content'];
    header("Content-length: ".$size.'"');
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats");
    error_reporting(0);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $name . '"');
    echo $content;
    exit;
}
//execute retrieval of files from database
$Download-> showDBFiles();
//pass results to output array 
$output = $Download->getMessages();
//var_dump($output);
} catch (Exception $e) {
$result[] = $e->getMessages();
}
```

This is where the functions dealing with the database are called:

```
        protected $messages = array();

        public function showDBFiles() {
            global $database;
            $sql = "SELECT resume_id, resume_title FROM ".self::$table_name;
            $result = $database->query($sql);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0){
                 $this->messages[] = "Database is empty";
            }else{
               while(list($id, $name) = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                  $this->messages[] = array('id'=>$id, 'name'=>$name);
                }

            }
        }

        public function getDBFiles($id) {
            global $database;
            $sql = "SELECT resume_title, file_type, file_size, resume_data FROM ".self::$table_name." WHERE resume_id = $id";
            $result = $database->query($sql);
            list($name, $type, $size, $content) = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $this->messages[] = array('name'=>$name, 'type'=>$type, 'size'=>$size, 'content'=>$content);        
        }

        public function getMessages()
        {
                return $this->messages;
        }
```

Comment: The figures are not visible.

Comment: Hi I've added them in, silly me haha

Comment: If you hard-code the content-type to "application/pdf" and then set `error_reporting(0);`, do you get the expected document? It looks like it's trying to output PDF content, but not correctly setting the content type because `$getFiles` isn't returning proper values. Also, you will want to remove the `var_dump`, as that will write content before you set headers.

Comment: Hi I've done that and I still can't download them. My output is now a php file

Comment: Trying moving `error_reporting(0);` to the top of the page. You may want to just set a value for the other headers. Just trying to isolate whether it's an issue with the data being returned for "type", etc.